# gzip and how to use it

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, server-side

seems a few sites i have read have differing options on how this is used. this is just a general "how do i make use of it" type question.

this is a very "for dummies" kind of question, so any pointers are greatly appreciated.

the source of this information was using [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) to analyze site load time.

Comment: In what context? You mean when serving content?

Comment: yes, i mean for compressing and displaying web content. i got this information from YSlow, and have no idea how to act on it.

Comment: Reference: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html

Comment: Random tutorial: http://www.howtoforge.com/apache2_mod_deflate (probably not the best there is, maybe somebody else has some more links)

Comment: @jason you will need to enable the module in the server's central configuration. The rest can be done in .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

mod_default is a burden on the server's cpu. Save your generated content into gzipped files and then serve them with mod_rewrite. I do so on my home page.

There was a great tutorial on how to do that, but it seems it has been deleted.
Google cache still has it, though.

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:tMvXiijTLgAJ:blog.astrumfutura.com/2009/01/zend-framework-page-caching-part-1-building-a-better-page-cache/+Zend+Framework+Page+Caching+part+1

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:j2q5eVEBdzEJ:blog.astrumfutura.com/2009/01/zend-framework-page-caching-part-2b-controller-based-cache-management/+Zend+Framework+Page+Caching+part+1

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Zf1e1cIcdhgJ:blog.astrumfutura.com/2009/01/zend-framework-page-caching-part-2-controller-based-cache-management/+Zend+Framework+Page+Caching:+Part+2

Have a look. Maybe it will suit you.